# Selenium IDE or Builder, can they connect with Selenium Server 2?

Tags: selenium

Is there any possible way to execute the output of either Selenium IDE browser plugin or Selenium Builder plugin with the selenium-server-standalone.jar?

When I try to execute the Selenium IDE selenese output with the -htmlSuite flag of the selenium-server JAR, the server complains that sendKeys is not a valid command.  sendKeys is a selenium V1 command, but the Selenium IDE outputs V2.  You'd think the server could execute V2 syntax, but it can't.

When I save V1 syntax from Selenium Builder, and try to execute that with the -htmlSuite flag I get an error that "click" does not implement the event interface.  (I'm guessing some other v1/v2 incompatibility)

There doesn't seem to be a way to execute the JSON output of Builder against the server either (there's a Jenkins plugin that claims to do this, but it doesn't seem to have enough logging or debug information to tell if it did anything at all).

Is there anyway to run the output of any GUI tool against Selenium Server 2?

UPDATE:
According to this bug, the selenese runner part of selenium server is abandoned.  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=4349  But why would someone bother compiling, packaging and shipping abandoned code that doesn't work?  I find it really hard to believe that something as popular as Selenium doesn't work with its own IDE browser plugin.

Comment: Are you using v2 of the selenium-server jar?

Comment: Yes, selenium-server-standalone-2.29.0.jar

Comment: What's your requirement here? Can't you just run the Selenium commands with Webdriver? The server part of selenium isn't needed any more in v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is, "no, Selenium Server v2 does not support Selenium IDE output nor Selenium Builder output".

If you want to use the output of Selenium IDE browser plugin you need the incredible Selenese Runner project.

https://github.com/vmi/selenese-runner-java

Why this requires a 3rd party tool and isn't part of the Selenium family of products is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.   First, do your research in the Selenium documentation and start a Selenium Grid on your computer.     Then, you can use Maven to run Selenium Builder scripts (using a method like what I have done here: http://djangofan.github.io/maven-selenium-builder/ )

Of course, for the Builder scripts to connect to the Grid hub you need to change the calls to:

```
new FirefoxDriver();
```

to this instead:

```
new RemoteWebDriver( "http://hubIP:4444/wd/hub", capabilities );
```

, or something similar.

Thats it.